# set focus to input box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the existing code:

```
 <form action="page.php?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p id="edit_name"><label for="name">Page Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars_decode($s->name);?>" id="name"> <input type="submit" src="../img/button_save.jpg" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" id="btnSubmit" class="submit"></p>
                <div id="show_name"<?= $_GET['edit'] ? ' style=" display: none"' : '' ?>><p><label for="name">Page Name:</label> <?PHP echo $s->name;?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>&edit_name=1" onClick="$('edit_name').show(); $('show_name').hide(); return false;"><img style="vertical-align: top;" src="../img/button_change.png" alt="Change Name"></a></p></div>
                <?
                // for non-JS browsers
                if(!$_GET['edit']) {
                    ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('edit_name').hide();
                </script>
                    <?
                }
                ?>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I want to also set focus to the input box on clicking change. Currently it just shows/hides upon clicking change.

Thanks!

Comment: you don't have an input field to focus... should there be one?

Comment: Don't drop stuff from `$_GET` directly into the page. You've just made a massive XSS security hole.

Comment: What is `$`? Prototype.js? Mootools? jQuery?

Comment: Looking at the way the PHP echo code tags are inter-mixed with the HTML makes me miss XSL, Velocity and the like... `<input name="{this.is}" value="{so.much}" onclick="{easier.to_read}"/>`.

Comment: @David Dorward - I added the PHP tag to the question... the $ is used as a variable prefix.

Comment: @scunliffe: `?><script type="text/javascript">$('edit_name').hide();` — **not** a PHP variable!

Comment: @David Dorward - ah true, I got lost in the edits for this question, the original one liner was chock full of PHP variables thus I presumed that was the item in question.  As someone else has indicated, it appears to be jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in one of the answers make the click handler unobstrusive.
Use the following code to focus the text box.

```
$(function(){
    $("id^=show_name a").click(function(){
        $('edit_name').show(); 
        $('show_name').hide(); 
        $("#name").focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Your HTML/PHP should now look like below:

```
 <form action="page.php?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
            <p id="edit_name"><label for="name">Page Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars_decode($s->name);?>" id="name"> <input type="submit" src="../img/button_save.jpg" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" id="btnSubmit" class="submit"></p>
            <div id="show_name"<?= $_GET['edit'] ? ' style=" display: none"' : '' ?>><p><label for="name">Page Name:</label> <?PHP echo $s->name;?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>&edit_name=1"><img style="vertical-align: top;" src="../img/button_change.png" alt="Change Name"></a></p></div>
            <?
            // for non-JS browsers
            if(!$_GET['edit']) {
                ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('edit_name').hide();
            </script>
                <?
            }
            ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#inputid").focus();
```

If you add that to the event that handles the displaying of the form (or add it to a document ready function such as

```
$(function(){
  $("#inputid").focus();
});
```

) it will also work on page load instead.